# Why is Safari 15 not triggering the audio events like `audio.onended`?

Tags: javascript, safari, ios15

I am trying to play some audio on the new Safari version(15), it plays the audio but does not trigger the `audio.onended` function.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (audio !== null) {
      audio.onended = () => console.log('hello');
    }
  }, [audio]);
```

Here is a screenshot when I test in safari:
https://gyazo.com/ebdc247bfd7195d9bcaa9bef7050b22c

Here is a screenshot when I tested in chrome:
https://gyazo.com/813d37a405cd54a0b736330876498887

As you can see on chrome, it is working well and in safari it is not triggering the `audio.onended`

Do you have similar problem as me? If you have how can I fix this issue?